# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple Data in View: BoundField Type Error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

The error `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BoundField'`

My form is a multiplechoicefield

```
SKILLS = ((1, 'Fly'),(2,'Run'))
class Form(forms.Form):
    ability = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), \
                                        choices = SKILLS, required=False)
```

now in my view i am trying to access each of the selcted data to perform a query

```
if "ability" in request.POST.keys():
    for ability in ability:
        x = ability
        sk = Skills.objects.get(id = x)
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you do:

```
if "ability" in request.POST.keys():
    for ability in ability:
        x = ability.value()
        sk = Skills.objects.get(id = x)
```

should work fine